# What is a receiver in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I'm confused as to what a 'receiver' is in Objective-C?

On the follwing site is says the following about what a receiver is:  https://quizlet.com/104540068/objective-c-flash-cards/

> "In Objective-C, you specify the object (known as the receiver of the
>   method) and the message being sent to that object by enclosing the
>   message expression in brackets."

I don't understand this.  I'm very new to Objective C.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Objective-C, a message is sent to a receiver.

The message is the method you are calling. The receiver is the what the message is called on.

Example. Let's say you have an `NSString`:

```
NSString *str = @"Hello";
```

Now you want to get the length of the string. You send the `length` message to `str`. `str` is the receiver of the message:

```
NSInteger len = [str length];
```

Basically, the receiver is the part on the left inside the square brackets and the message is the part on the right in the square brackets.